# How to use unionAll to combine two tables into one table in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I have two tables that can be linked by id. I want to use dolphindb in unionAll to combine the two tables into one. I tried the following two ways but it didn’t work

```
t1=table(1 2 3 as id, 11 12 13 as x)
t2=table(3 4 5 as id, `a`b`c as x)
unionAll(t1,t2);
/*Error：
unionAll(t1, t2) => Failed to append data to column 'x' 
*/
```

and this way

```
t1=table(1 2 3 as id, 11 12 13 as x)
t2=table(3 4 5 as id, `a`b`c as x)
unionAll(t1,t2,true);
/*Error：
unionAll(t1, t2, 1) => The data type of column [x] of the input table [#1] is inconsistent with that of other input tables.
*/
```

not sure how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data types in the x columns of t1 and t2 are different, they cannot be merged into the one column.
You can modify the column name in t2 from x to y, and then use “unionAll “to connect:

```py
t1=table(1 2 3 as id, 11 12 13 as x)
t2=table(3 4 5 as id, `a `b `c as y)
unionAll(t1,t2, true)
```

The result is:

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |  |
| 2 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 13 |  |
| 3 |  | a |
| 4 |  | b |
| 5 |  | c |